# Problem using installed packages with PIP (possibly due to two Python versions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, package

When I try to use installed packages in Python, I nearly always run into the same error.
So I e.g. install a package like this: `pip3 install mathplot` and when I afterwards want to use it in Python3 (I use `python3` in the command prompt), I run into the ModuleNotFoundError:

```
>>> import mathplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mathplot'
```

But when I run just `python`, the module is found and ready to use.
Any idea where this problem comes from and how I can get rid of it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would first make sure `pip3` and `python3` point to the same installation. Which is the output of `which pip3` and `which python3` (assuming you are on Linux)? One thing you could try right away is `python3 -m pip install mathplot`, and then try to import it using your `python3` alias.

Comment: @luizbarcelos thank you so much. This command works for me. pip3 and python3 are in the same folder. Strange where the error comes from... but at least it works with this command. Thanks